# RxJS Subject never pushed the first next

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, rxjs

Im having issues with subjects and a comment system Im building out. It works fine but the first comment that is posted never shows up until someone posts another comment, all other comments work fine after this. I have tried with BehaviourSubject giving an initial value of null or "" and ReplaySubject but I think I might be missing something with how these work, is there anyway to have this work in realtime i.e when a user pushes a comment it goes to the server and is added back onto the stack without having to submit a second comment right away ?

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable"
import { BehaviorSubject } from "rxjs/BehaviorSubject"
// import {Subject} from "rxjs/Subject"
import { ServerAPI } from '../serverapi';
import { ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs/internal/ReplaySubject';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class Comments {
    private _comments = new Subject<any[]>();
    $comments: Observable<any> = this._comments.asObservable();

    constructor(private api: ServerAPI) {
        this.$comments.subscribe(() => {
            console.log('comments sub\'d');
        });
    }

    async comment(threadID: string, commentData: any): Promise<any> {
        await this.api.postComment(threadID, commentData);
        const fetchComments = await this.api.getComments(threadID);
        this._comments.next(fetchComments);
    }
}
```

In my template I received the comments via subscribe li

```js
this.comment.$comments.subscribe(chats => {
    this.CommentData = chats;
});
```

Comment: Have you ensured that yout 'template' subscription is done after the first emission? If it is done before, you will never get that value using a Subject. Despite that, you said that with a BehaviourSubject doesn't work? it should... can you test it again? When you subscribe to a behaiviour subject it always return the last value, it should emit something when subscribing.

Comment: can you add a stackblitz ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a function to subscribe on the subject like this

```
getData() {
    return this._comments.asObservable();
}
```

So this is how you  subscribe to getData() in your component

```
this.service.getData().subscribe(x=> {
   console.log(x);
});
```

Also subscribe in constructor like you done right now will only execute one

```
constructor(private api: ServerAPI) {
    this.$comments.subscribe(() => {
        console.log('comments sub\'d');
    });
}
```

Comment: Why does it not work to simply subscribe the way I am on the observable variable ? ```$comments: Observable<any> = this._comments.asObservable();```

Comment: I'm not sure but this is how you get data from subject.

Comment: I dont think theres any difference or advantages over what you propose and what I am already doing - it looks like basically the same this other than you put it in a function